# auto validation input HTML

Tags: html, forms, date, input

In my website, I have a form with 5 inputs. I have an input with a date to valid by user, this date is validated by a click on the submit button. My question is,  is it possible to validate automaticaly an input date? 
The user selects the date and the submit is automatic.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

On input, set `type=date`, and set argument `required` (this is boolean).

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NECAF/)